# What does eclipse do when you inspect variables (while debugging)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, debugging, hibernate-envers

I have an instance of `org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.ListProxy` that is causing some grief: whenever I programmatically try to access it I get a null pointer exception (ie calling `list.size()`) but when I first inspect the object using Eclipse's variable inspector I see Hibernate generate a SQL statement and the list changes dynamically. Then everything works. How can I do the same thing programmatically? I've tried `list.toString()` but that doesn't seem to help.

**Update 1**

Don't know if this helps but when I first click on the list instance I see in the display:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

Then database query runs and when I click again I get the correct `.toString()` result.

**Update 2**

Here is the original exception I get (when I don't inspect the element in debug mode).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.EntitiesAtRevisionQuery.list(EntitiesAtRevisionQuery.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.OneToOneNotOwningMapper.mapToEntityFromMap(OneToOneNotOwningMapper.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.MultiPropertyMapper.mapToEntityFromMap(MultiPropertyMapper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.EntityInstantiator.createInstanceFromVersionsEntity(EntityInstantiator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.component.MiddleRelatedComponentMapper.mapToObjectFromFullMap(MiddleRelatedComponentMapper.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.ListCollectionInitializor.addToCollection(ListCollectionInitializor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.ListCollectionInitializor.addToCollection(ListCollectionInitializor.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.AbstractCollectionInitializor.initialize(AbstractCollectionInitializor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.checkInit(CollectionProxy.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.size(CollectionProxy.java:55)
    at <MY CODE HERE, which checks list.size()>
```

**Final Solution (Actually more of a temporary hack)**

```
boolean worked = false;
while (!worked) {
    try {
        if(list.size() == 1) {
            // do stuff 
        }
        worked = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: exception must be accessed or the loop will be infinite
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what happends there is you're seing Hibernate's lazy loading in deep action :)

Basically hibernate loads proxy classes for you lazily associated relations, such that instead of a List of classes C you get a List (actually a PersistenceBag implementation) of Hibernate autogenerated proxie for your C class. THis is hibernate's way of deferring load of that association's values until they are actually accessed. So that's why when you access it in the eclipse debugger (which basically accesses an instance's fields/methids via introspection) you see the sql hibernate triggers to fetch the needed data.

The trick here is that depending on WHEN you access a lazy collection you might get different results. If you access it using the eclipse debugger you're more likely still in the Hibernate session that started loading that thing, so everything works as expected, an sql is (lazily) triggered when the thing is accessed and the data is loaded). Problem is that if you wanna access that same data in your code, but at a point where the session is already closed, you'll either get a LazyInitializationException or null (the latter if you're using some library for cleaning put hibenrate proxises such as Gilead)

Comment: The code that fails (throws the exception) is right where I have my breakpoint set, so obviously the session is still valid right? The difference is that if I step over the next line it blows up but if I inspect with Eclipse THEN step over the next line it works.

Comment: I think the error occcurs when the eclipse debugger accesses the fileds as well, it's that it is simply ingored by eclipse who continues. What is the exact error you get when you do NOT debug/step over with eclipse?

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that... I'll attach the exception to the original question.

Comment: Turns out that Eclipse was catching the exception as you mentioned, so I ended up doing the same thing as a workaround for now (catch exception, inspect exception, retry).

Comment: Look, not to be a bummer, but sometimes Hibernate just has bugs that show up as unexpected exceptions such as that. try looking your exception on the hibernate jira: https://hibernate.onjira.com

Comment: Actually I did end up finding it, and it's unresolved: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6317

Comment: Yep, that happends sometimes. As an alternative you could try EclipseLink (JPA2 implementation): http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/